# R Combining lists with functionals

Tags: r, list, function

I'm new to functionals in R so this question comes from a lack of basic knowledge.

I have 2 lists. Both lists contain a large amount of datasets, have the same length and headings. What I want is to add a column to all the dataframes in list 1, based on a simple equation between the 2 lists.
For each list I want to do the following:

```
temp$zscore <- (temp$Rho - zscore$mean)/zscore$SD
```

Any usefull documentation/tutorial on working with lists is also well appreciated.

List 1:

```
> Output2
$E1
   chr start   end ID gene_id gene_name  Rho Pval
1 chr1 10046 10550 E1    9999      9999 9999 9999

$E2
     chr  start    end ID           gene_id      gene_name         Rho       Pval
2   chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000177757.1         FAM87B  0.05054603 0.84212228
21  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000187583.6        PLEKHN1  0.41706072 0.08508920
22  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000187608.5          ISG15  0.24045408 0.33504436
23  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000187634.6         SAMD11  0.22807018 0.36116656
24  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000187642.5       C1orf170 -0.02537278 0.92039607
25  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000187961.9         KLHL17  0.48115649 0.04322426
26  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000188157.9           AGRN  0.10010320 0.69253961
27  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000188290.6           HES4  0.04024768 0.87580888
28  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000188976.6          NOC2L  0.11053725 0.66236936
29  chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000223764.2    RP11-54O7.3  0.32693838 0.18542180
210 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000225880.4      LINC00115  0.24677339 0.32355096
211 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000228327.2  RP11-206L10.2  0.08363450 0.74144830
212 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000228794.4 RP11-206L10.11 -0.05675955 0.82419663
213 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000230092.3  RP11-206L10.8  0.18703827 0.45738249
214 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000230368.2         FAM41C  0.09448420 0.70920788
215 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000230699.2    RP11-54O7.1  0.30385847 0.22025296
216 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000237491.4  RP11-206L10.9  0.40378010 0.09656416
217 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000240453.1 RP11-206L10.10  0.21152401 0.39945835
218 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000240618.1  RP11-206L10.5  0.56290835 0.01500755
219 chr1 712903 715448 E2 ENSG00000272512.1   RP11-54O7.17  0.15830049 0.53041538
```

Example dataframes list 2:

```
> zscore
$E1
       mean        SD
1 -0.111857 0.2508317

$E2
        mean        SD
1 0.09520034 0.2050961
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `Map`, that maps a function to its following arguments, in this case the two lists `list1` and `list2`:

```
f <- function(x, y){
  x[['zscore']] <- (x[['Rho']] - y[['mean']])/y[['SD']]
  x
}

Map(f, list1, list2)
#[[1]]
#         Rho      Pval    zscore
#1 0.05054603 0.8421223 0.6055256
#2 0.41706072 0.0850892 2.0601302
#3 0.24045408 0.3350444 1.3592229
#
#[[2]]
#         Rho      Pval    zscore
#1 0.05054603 0.8421223 0.6055256
#2 0.41706072 0.0850892 2.0601302
#3 0.24045408 0.3350444 1.3592229
```

**Data**

```
temp <- read.table(text = "
         Rho      Pval
  0.05054603 0.8421223
  0.41706072 0.0850892
  0.24045408 0.3350444
", header = TRUE)

zscore <- read.table(text = "
      mean                SD
1     -0.1020274           0.2519686
", header = TRUE)

list1 <- list(temp, temp)
list2 <- list(zscore, zscore)
```

**Edit**

With the new data structure, the following updated function seems to be more fit to solve the problem.

```
f <- function(x, y){
  x[['E1']][['zscore']] <- (x[['E1']][['Rho']] - y[['E1']][['mean']])/y[['E1']][['SD']]
  x
}
```

Comment: Hmm its not working for me.. Both lists contain multiple dataframes as the one I've added. Maybe I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @joffie Both test lists contain 2 df's each. Can you please post a better example of your data? Maybe it's not working because the example of list2 is `zscore$E1`. What is this `E1`?

Comment: Hmm you're right... When I use your data it does work. I will improve my example

Comment: E1 was the name of the list. I've updated it to the non-simplified version. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, sorry, it was my bad. Fixed the problem and now it works. Thanks!